# Laravel If Statments with DB data

Tags: laravel

All,

So I am building an application that will need to have a roster of people and their certifications for this particular organization. I want to color coat the cells in the table for the roster based on what certification they have. I was thinking something with if statements, but wasn't sure where to put (controller or on the page) it nor how to do it exactly. Here is what I have so far (Just put it in standard PHP to put it in here easier):

```
             echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th>$controller->name</th>";
                    echo "<th>$controller->oi</th>";
                    echo "<th>$controller->rating</th>";
                    echo "<th>$controller->type</th>";
                    echo "<th>$controller->gnd</th>";
                    echo "<th>$controller->twr</th>";
                    echo "<th>$controller->app</th>";
                    echo "<th>$controller->ctr</th>";
                    echo "<th>$controller->oce</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to color code all the cells in the row or individual cells?

Comment: Individual cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a property on the certificate object that would work as a valid CSS class name, you can echo that on the classes and then set the colors up in your CSS. If you don't have anything that is a valid class name (e.g. has spaces), Laravel has a [kebab_case](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-kebab-case) method you could use to format the string into something that might work as a class name (or some other helper method).

So, if certificate type = "some-type":

```
<th class="{{ $certificate->type }}">...</th>
```

And CSS:

```
.some-type {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I could do it like if they have the cert, then the color would change based on the "type?"

Comment: Yeah, you would assign the colors in the CSS based on type.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment because I have joined recently and I do not have that much credit yet.

The good practice says "do your logic in BE". In another words it is better to avoid if statements in your template, but it is not a big deal, at the end you will have a cleaner code. You can adjust any certificate with a color code and send the color code along with your data to your template file.

Assuming that you wanna use blade for your FE (and I advice you to use that if you do not have a better option):

```
<tr>
                <th>{{ $controller->name }}</th>
                <th>{{ $controller->oi }}</th>
                <th>{{ $controller->rating }}</th>
                <th>{{ $controller->type }}</th>
                <th>{{ $controller->gnd }}</th>
                <th>{{ $controller->twr }}</th>
                <th>{{ $controller->app }}</th>
                <th>{{ $controller->ctr }}</th>
                <th>{{ $controller->oce }}</th>
</tr>
```

I suggest you doing the following:
the certificate table for a roster:

```
@foreach($roster->certificates as $certificate)
    <tr style="color: {{$certificate->color}}">
       <th>{{$certificate->name}}</th>
       <th>{{$certificate->anything}}</th>
       ....
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Please let me know for any question.